# 100% Height on Div affecting Footer

Tags: html, css

I have a simple problem, that I'm sure you all will solve in no time.

I am trying to use percentage heights on my child divs but that requires me to use 100% height on the parent div. However, the footer only accounts for the height of the parent div, and therefore shows up in the middle of the page. What is the right way to do this?

My code is essentially:

```
<body style="height: 100%">
<div style="height: 100%">
    <div id="child" style="height: 50%">
    </div>
    <div id="child" style="height: 50%">
    </div>
    <div id="child" style="height: 50%">
    </div>
    <div id="child" style="height: 50%">
    </div>
</div>
<footer> </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to use id on a unique element, so please use class instead.

```html
<body>
<div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 50vh"> child </div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 50vh"> child </div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 50vh"> child </div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 50vh"> child </div>
</div>
<footer> Footer </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Not what I wanted to know. And that's not even my code, it's just some random thing I wrote to show you the HEIGHT. I don't care about ID vs. class.
BUT... Is vh an universally accepted unit now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` to place the footer at the bottom

```
#footer {
width:100%;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background:#ee5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">

 #footer {
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 background:#ee5;
}</style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%">
<div style="height: 100%">
    <div id="child" style="height: 50%">
    <h1>first div</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="child" style="height: 50%">
    <h1>div again</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="child" style="height: 50%">
    <h1>Just another div</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="child" style="height: 50%">
    <h1>Another Div</h1>
    </div>
    <footer style="background-color:green" id="footer"><h1>Footer</h1> </footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, I couldn't get this to show your issue in jsfiddle, but it did come up in plain html tests.

This works like you're expecting it to if you use min-height on your first div.

Code:

```
<body style="height: 100%">
  <div style="min-height: 100%">
    <div class="child" style="height: 50%">a</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 50%">b</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 50%">c</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 50%">d</div>
  </div>
  <footer> FOOTER</footer>
</body>
```

Nitpicky footnote: it's a really bad idea to use the same id for multiple elements.